# Paperclip is not storing alternative sizes for one model, but does for another

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip

I have two models which have attached images. The first one is defined like this:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_attached_file :cover_image, styles: { large: "750x750^", medium: "600x600>", thumb: "100x100>" }, default_url: ":style/missing.gif"
  validates_attachment_content_type :cover_image, content_type: /\Aimage\/.*\Z/
end
```

This works perfectly, and stores a total of 4 images in my /public folder.

My second model though...

```
class Lesson < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_attached_file :image, styles: { large: "750x750^", medium: "600x600>", thumb: "100x100>" }, default_url: ":style/missing.gif"
  validates_attachment_content_type :image, content_type: /\Aimage\/.*\Z/
end
```

... only stores the orginal image in a folder called original.

My server logs do show something like this in the POST request:

```
Command :: file -b --mime '/var/folders/2b/q6z4f1fn58s83fbx77xwsk5h0000gn/T/64ecce8dbf7049731a63696ae4d7933020151207-39937-jxf7m7.jpg'
Command :: identify -format '%wx%h,%[exif:orientation]' '/var/folders/2b/q6z4f1fn58s83fbx77xwsk5h0000gn/T/64ecce8dbf7049731a63696ae4d7933020151207-39937-wmm770.jpg[0]' 2>/dev/null
Command :: identify -format %m '/var/folders/2b/q6z4f1fn58s83fbx77xwsk5h0000gn/T/64ecce8dbf7049731a63696ae4d7933020151207-39937-wmm770.jpg[0]'
Command :: convert '/var/folders/2b/q6z4f1fn58s83fbx77xwsk5h0000gn/T/64ecce8dbf7049731a63696ae4d7933020151207-39937-wmm770.jpg[0]' -auto-orient -resize "750x750^" '/var/folders/2b/q6z4f1fn58s83fbx77xwsk5h0000gn/T/a802cd21677cc830b7ba993a8ff7edd920151207-39937-1p9h15m'
Command :: identify -format '%wx%h,%[exif:orientation]' '/var/folders/2b/q6z4f1fn58s83fbx77xwsk5h0000gn/T/64ecce8dbf7049731a63696ae4d7933020151207-39937-wmm770.jpg[0]' 2>/dev/null
Command :: identify -format %m '/var/folders/2b/q6z4f1fn58s83fbx77xwsk5h0000gn/T/64ecce8dbf7049731a63696ae4d7933020151207-39937-wmm770.jpg[0]'
Command :: convert '/var/folders/2b/q6z4f1fn58s83fbx77xwsk5h0000gn/T/64ecce8dbf7049731a63696ae4d7933020151207-39937-wmm770.jpg[0]' -auto-orient -resize "600x600>" '/var/folders/2b/q6z4f1fn58s83fbx77xwsk5h0000gn/T/a802cd21677cc830b7ba993a8ff7edd920151207-39937-r4bxgl'
Command :: identify -format '%wx%h,%[exif:orientation]' '/var/folders/2b/q6z4f1fn58s83fbx77xwsk5h0000gn/T/64ecce8dbf7049731a63696ae4d7933020151207-39937-wmm770.jpg[0]' 2>/dev/null
Command :: identify -format %m '/var/folders/2b/q6z4f1fn58s83fbx77xwsk5h0000gn/T/64ecce8dbf7049731a63696ae4d7933020151207-39937-wmm770.jpg[0]'
Command :: convert '/var/folders/2b/q6z4f1fn58s83fbx77xwsk5h0000gn/T/64ecce8dbf7049731a63696ae4d7933020151207-39937-wmm770.jpg[0]' -auto-orient -resize "100x100>" '/var/folders/2b/q6z4f1fn58s83fbx77xwsk5h0000gn/T/a802cd21677cc830b7ba993a8ff7edd920151207-39937-4zvubq'
Command :: file -b --mime '/var/folders/2b/q6z4f1fn58s83fbx77xwsk5h0000gn/T/64ecce8dbf7049731a63696ae4d7933020151207-39937-19vrckc.jpg'
```

Could this be caused by the name of the field? Any other ideas maybe?

**EDIT**
My Lesson model is actually a bit more complex as that it's using a shared table to differentiate content type:

```
class Lesson < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.table_name = 'steps'
  default_scope { where(content_type: name) }
  has_attached_file :cover_image, styles: { large: "750x750^", medium: "600x600>", thumb: "100x100>" }, default_url: ":style/missing.gif"
  validates_attachment_content_type :cover_image, content_type: /\Aimage\/.*\Z/

  validates :title, presence: true, length: { maximum: 255 }

  def self.create_for_course(course, attributes = {})
    content = new(attributes)
    if content.valid?
      step = Step.create(content_type: name, course: course)
      instance = step.becomes(self)
      instance.update_attributes(attributes)
      instance
    else
      step = content.becomes(Step)
      step.course = course
      step.content_type = name
      step.becomes(self)
    end
  end
  #include Content
  #restrict_attrs :title, :content_body, :cover_image_file_name, :cover_image_content_type, :cover_image_file_size, :cover_image_updated_at, :cover_image

end
```

Comment: The only diff I can see is that `cover_image` vs `image` name -- do you have the correct columns in each table?

Comment: Yep, I have... I just renamed the column for the second model to cover_image as well, still only saving the original file.

Comment: Even stranger is that paperclip object seems to think that it did successfully created the images... because the various types do return the correct URI -> `Lesson.first.cover_image(:large)` does give the expected URI, only the file is not at that location. Is there someway to debug the file saving?

Comment: Don't think so, I'm writing an answer which may help

Comment: My Lesson model is a bit more complex... since it's using another table to store the data. Maybe that's causing the problems. I'll update my code.

Comment: Sort of... It uses normal ActiveRecord::Base but stores in a shared table and sets default scope.

Comment: Bad practice - I think my answer will give you a better way

Comment: Ok, I'm curious, thanks in advance. I found out that updating my record does save the correct alternatiev formats. So I suppose the dual record saving caused by the STI hack is causing the problems.

Comment: Np, I wrote my answer. We've been working on cutting out the need for "middleman" models (`Post::Entry`), but having a central `Asset` model has been amazing -- we've had CkEditor and a bunch of other models using it with no issues :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was too long for a comment; you'll benefit from using the [`paperclip_defaults`](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip#defaults) option:

```
#config/application.rb
...
config.paperclip_defaults = {
   styles: { large: "750x750^", medium: "600x600>", thumb: "100x100>" },     
   default_url: ":style/missing.gif"
}
```

This will allow you to just call the attachment name in your models *and* override the defaults if you so wish:

```
#app/models/post.rb
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_attached_file :cover_image
  validates_attachment_content_type :cover_image, content_type: /\Aimage\/.*\Z/
end
```

--

In respect to your error, I'm not sure what the problem might be.

I have a suggestion though. It's a little tricky, but if you can get it working, it makes all your models super dry.

[Here's a link](http://rails-bestpractices.com/posts/2010/08/18/use-sti-and-polymorphic-model-for-multiple-uploads/):

```
#app/models/asset.rb
class Asset < ActiveRecord::Base
    #Associations
    ##################
    belongs_to :assetable, polymorphic: true

    #Paperclip
    ##################
    delegate :url, to: :attachment

########################################

    ##################
    #     Methods    #
    ##################
    before_create :dimensions #-> https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/wiki/Extracting-image-dimensions

    #Width & Height
    def dimensions
        return unless image? && has_dimensions?
        self.width  = geometry.width
        self.height = geometry.height
    end

    ########

    private

    #Geometry -> https://github.com/galetahub/ckeditor/blob/master/lib/ckeditor/backend/paperclip.rb#L23
    def geometry
        @geometry ||= begin
            file = attachment.respond_to?(:queued_for_write) ? attachment.queued_for_write[:original] : attachment.to_file
            ::Paperclip::Geometry.from_file(file)
        end
    end

    #Image?
    def image?
        image_types = %w(image/jpeg image/png image/gif image/jpg image/pjpeg image/tiff image/x-png)
        image_types.include? attachment_content_type
    end

    #Dimensions
    def has_dimensions?
        respond_to?(:width) && respond_to?(:height)
    end
end
```

Assets table:
[image]

This can then be used with STI's:

```
#app/models/post.rb
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_one :cover, class_name: "Post::Cover", as: :assetable, dependent: :destroy
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :cover, reject_if: :all_blank
   has
end

#app/models/post/cover.rb
class Post::Cover < Asset
   has_attached_file :attachment
end
```

This allows you to set the `cover` attribute as a nested association, but will have the added benefit of storing all the assets in your App in the `assets` table:

[image]

--

**Update**

You could use the following to make your `create_for_course` method DRYer:

```
#app/models/post.rb
class Lesson < ActiveRecord::Base
   attr_reader :course

   belongs_to :step
   before_create :set_step, if Proc.new { |a| a.course }

   private

   def set_step
      self.step.create(course: course) #-> we can use the course virtual attribute)
   end
end
```

Although I doubt it catches your functionality specifically, it *would* allow you to run:

```
lesson = Lesson.create course: "5"
# automatically creates "step" with course of "5" and current lesson
```

Comment: Thanks for your extensive reply. I think that my problem is caused by the fact that I need to store a Step before I can correctly store a Lesson, like defined in `self.create_for_course(course, attributes = {})`. If I call save directly on the `content = new(attributes)`, the extra variants do get created.

Comment: Hmm I didn't see your updated code. Why aren't you using `before_create` with a virtual attribute? like `before_create ... if: Proc.new { |a| a.course? }`

Comment: You're trying to invoke a custom class method - `create_for_course`. This, I take it, is to replace `Model.create` so that you can create your `Step` object. Instead of doing that, why don't you just make a `before_create` which only runs when you have a virtual attribute set? This way, your code will be much dryer. I'll write an update if you want?

Comment: Yeah, that would be a great learning opportunity for me... fairly new to Rails. Thanks!

Comment: Nice using `becomes` btw! What experience do you have prior to this?

Comment: A few years of PHP... but based this code on an example I've found online. I wanted to be able to create various types of data without the need of multiple tables and without STI. Thought this was a pretty nice solution.

Comment: Why don't you want to use `STI`?

Comment: I'd rather not... I now faked STI with the use of normal ActiveRecord Models.

Comment: But your method for attaching images is really sweet!

Comment: Yes, perfect! Really appreciated.